# What am I? Now you see me now you don't

Tags: riddle

> Now you see me now you don't,
>
> Now you see me now you don't,
>
> What am I?

A hint if you'd like one:

> Animal-related

A second hint if you're still stuck:

> You see it on the road

Comment: There may be too many possible answers here… Maybe you could add a bit of context or some more clues.

Comment: Hints should not be necessary to solve the riddle. Your riddle as it currently stands is *far* too broad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What am I?

> Zebra crossing

Now you see me now you don't,
Now you see me now you don't,

> As you approach the signal or see people crossing through the zebra crossing, you see it and when you pass by you don't.

A hint if you'd like one:

Animal-related

> Resembles the zebra's b/w stripes.

You see it on the road

> Its on the road to give priority to pedestrians to cross the road amidst traffic.

Answer (score 2):

What am I?

> chameleon.

Now you see me now you don't

> They are able to camouflage.

Comment: But there are many animals that can do this. Why that specific one? Granted it is common.

Answer (score 1):

> [Raised pavement marker](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raised_pavement_marker); sometimes known as a "cat's eye" or "road turtle."

Now you see me, now you don't, now you do, now you don't:

> You seen them over and over as you're driving.

Hint 1:

> Also, animal names.

Hint 2:

> Lastly, seen on roads.

Comment: I was going to say that, but I couldn't think of the name, nice one!

Answer (score 0):

Many possibilities here, but I like this one:

*Now you see me now you don't,*

*Now you see me now you don't,*

*What am I?*

> I think this could be a lighthouse – some, but not all lighthouses have a light that is alternately on and off. Perhaps there may be significance to making the statement twice.

Or since it's an animal:

> How 'bout a lightning bug?

Comment: Not the answer, but good try! I like your explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's a suggestion (invalidated after the second hint was released)

> A flying fish

The main reason is:

> Use of the words see and how it sounds like sea

Also:

> Flying fish jump in and out of water frequently, now you see them, now you don't repeatedly

And:

> Young flying fish are initially eggs, visible, then they have camouflage filaments naturally, so now you don't see them, then as they grow older the filaments go away so they are seen again, and then they jump in and out of water, repeating the cycle of seen / unseen

And:

> Flying fish use this method to escape predators, dazzling them, probably appearing to the predators as almost magical, conveying the magical connotations associated with the phrase "Now you see me, now you don't"

Comment: Good effort for scientific explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Moths

Explanation:

> When driving, especially in the countryside, the moths are attracted to the head lights, and they appear out of nowhere as the light reflects off their bodies. And sometimes, they hit the windshield.